# Replicate "background-attachment: fixed" for mobile. Parallax causing offset

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, parallax

I have a magazine template which goes as follows:

```
    <div class="article"> <div class="image" style="background-image: url();"> </div>
        <div class="text">
        <h1>House Quiz Ends In Equilibrium</h1>
    <p>
   Blah blah blah
    </p>
    <h3 align="right"> By Matthew Bradley, Year 14 </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to maintain my code as much as possible but include a scrolling effect that replicates background-attachment: fixed as I found that it does not work on mobile and would like a similar experience across all platforms. I have experimented with code for parallax scrolling but due to the  div being copy and pasted to create new articles, this means that images (rendered as backgrounds to have the "fixed" property for the scrolling) for articles lower down the page are pushed up so much that you can see the solid colour background. Does anyone have a solution to this? Is there any way to negate the amount scrolled down the page to ensure the background stays in place like with "fixed"?

Comment: You will need a customized, very tall picture for that or background repeatY.